# How can i create a third column for integer values?

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

i want to create a SQL Database using SQL Lite in Java.

```
String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME
            + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + COL2 +" TEXT, "
            + COL3 +" INTEGER"
            + ")";
```

I have this getTime Method:

```
public Cursor getTime(String name){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT " + COL3 + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME +
            " WHERE " + COL2 + " = '" + name + "'";
    Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    return data;
}
```

And a method for updating time:

```
public void updateTime(int id, String name, int time) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME + " SET " + COL3 +
            " = '" + time + "' WHERE " + COL1 + " = '" + id + "'" +
            " AND " + COL2 + " = '" + name + "'";
    Log.d(TAG, "updateName: query: " + query);
    Log.d(TAG, "updateName: Setting time to " + time);
    db.execSQL(query);
}
```

I use getTime() like this:

```
Cursor test = mDatabaseHelper.getTime(selectedName);
    int timeTest = test.getInt(0); <-- Error here!
    System.out.print(timeTest);
```

For some reason anything is not working how i want it to do.
Thanks for your help :D

Comment: Please explain what "not working" means for you here.

Comment: Cursor test = mDatabaseHelper.getTime(selectedName);
    int timeTest = test.getInt(0); <----- I get an error here
    System.out.print(timeTest);

Comment: If you are not using command parameters, at least escape single quotes to prevent [SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp). `" = '" + name.Replace("'", "''") + "'"`.

Answer (score 0):

You must check if the `Cursor` has fetched any rows with `moveToFirst()`:

```
Cursor test = mDatabaseHelper.getTime(selectedName);
int timeTest = 0;
if (test.moveToFirst()) {
    timeTest = test.getInt(0); 
    System.out.print(timeTest);
} else {
    System.out.print("No rows matching");
}
```

**Edit**
The title of your question seems unrelated to everything you mention later, 
**but** is there a case that you have already created the table 
and now you want to add the `COL3` column? 
If so, uninstall the app so the database is deleted and rerun so it is recreated with the new column.  
The code in the `CREATE TABLE...` statement does not create the table if it already exists.